# Get Image Height and Width as integer values?

Tags: php

I've tried to use the PHP function [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), but I was unable to extract the image width and height as an integer value.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Try like this:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('path_to_image');
```

Make sure that:

1. You specify the correct image path there
2. The image has read access
3. Chmod image dir to 755

Also try to prefix path with `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, this helps sometimes when you are not able to read files.

Comment: 777 on directory is not needed.

Comment: @poke: are you really 100% sure?

Comment: Yes. 777 means read, write and execute right for owner, group, and all. You need read and execute right to access a directory, but you don't need write right; and you also don't need that right for everybody. 755 should be fine for every access where you don't need to create files inside of the directory.

Comment: Interesting to me that you need execute rights on the directory but not the image itself (works with the image on 644).

Comment: You need *allow_url_fopen* turned on to be able to use `getimagesize()` on remote images.

Comment: @Lee: On a directory, x refers to traversal, not execution.  I.e. permission to view the contents.

Comment: Can you explain why I am getting the correct data this way list($height, $width) = getimagesize('path_to_image'); array 0 index is height and 1 index is width

Answer (score 69):

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename)
```

Or,

```
$data = getimagesize($filename);
$width = $data[0];
$height = $data[1];
```

Answer (score 13):

getimagesize() returns an array containing the image properties.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/image.jpg");
```

to just get the width and height or

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr)
```

to get some more information.

Answer (score 8):

Like this :

```
imageCreateFromPNG($var);
//I don't know where from you get your image, here it's in the png case
// and then :
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
echo $width;
echo $height;
```

Comment: Don't work: `getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`, function `getimagesize` expects filename

Answer (score 6):

PHP's `getimagesize()` returns an array of data. The first two items in the array are the two items you're interested in: the width and height. To get these, you would simply request the first two indexes in the returned array:

```
var $imagedata = getimagesize("someimage.jpg");

print "Image width  is: " . $imagedata[0];
print "Image height is: " . $imagedata[1];
```

For further information, see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

Answer (score 6):

`getimagesize('image.jpg')`
function works only if `allow_url_fopen` is set to 1 or On inside php.ini file on the server,
if it is not enabled, one should use 
`ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);` 
on top of the file where getimagesize() function is used.