# Get image height and width PHP

Tags: php, image, image-size

Hello I need to get the height and width on the fly of an uploaded image.

This is the PHP function I am using, but it does not return anything for the width and height..

Could you please help me?

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["Artwork"]);
$min_width = "1000";
$min_height = "1000";
if ((($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["Artwork"]["size"] < 20000000) && ($width > $min_width) && ($height > $min_height) && ($width == $height))
  {


  if ($_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] . "<br />";


   }else{
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Artwork"]["tmp_name"],
      $path_image . $imageName);
      header("Location: http://pitchmystuff.co.uk/m/digidist/tracks/".$idAlbum."");
      }



   }else{
    //echo "invalid file";

    echo '<script>
    alert("There was an error uploading your coverart file. Please check the requirements and try again.'.$width.$height.'");
    document.location ="http://pitchmystuff.co.uk/m/digidist/albums/";
    </script>';


    }
```

Comment: `getimagesize()` is the ticket. You are just not using the right variable as the parameter. There should be an error message to that effect: Activate error reporting to see it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Image Height and Width as integer values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179100/get-image-height-and-width-as-integer-values)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Should be

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["Artwork"]['tmp_name']);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: It's giving me $width value in $height and vice versa for some of images, would you please suggest me something for the same?

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php

$imagedetails = getimagesize($_FILES['Artwork']['tmp_name']);
$width = $imagedetails[0];
$height = $imagedetails[1];

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
/*$size = getimagesize("http://heartbeatperformance.com.p9.hostingprod.com/customerphotos/photoes/51HDE3cnl2L.jpg");

list($width, $height) = $size;
echo "width: $width<br />height: $height";*/



$testing = "http://heartbeatperformance.com.p9.hostingprod.com/customerphotos/img/logo.png";
//echo $testing;
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($testing);
echo "Image width " . $width;
echo "Image height " . $height;



?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$DOCS_NAME = $_FILES['DOCS']['name'];
$DOCS_SIZE = getimagesize($_FILES['DOCS']['tmp_name']);
$DOCS      = file_get_contents ($_FILES['DOCS']['tmp_name']);
$FILE_SIZE = $_FILES["DOCS"]["size"];
$FILE_TYPE = $_FILES["DOCS"]["type"];

echo 'Width     = '.$DOCS_SIZE[0]. "<br />";
echo 'Height    = '.$DOCS_SIZE[1]. "<br />";;  
echo '2         = '.$DOCS_SIZE[2]. "<br />";;  
echo '3         = '.$DOCS_SIZE[3]. "<br />";;  
echo 'bits      = '.$DOCS_SIZE['bits']. "<br />";;
echo 'channels  = '.$DOCS_SIZE['channels']. "<br />";;
echo 'mime      = '.$DOCS_SIZE['mime']. "<br />";
echo 'type      = '.$_FILES["DOCS"]["type"]. "<br />";
echo 'size      = '.$_FILES["DOCS"]["size"]. "<br />";
```