# How i get width and height of a image in Laravel Framework?

Tags: laravel, file-upload

In this image,

[image]

I can get the `width` and `height` of the image in the directory.

But i want to get the width and height of a picture before i upload the image.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please add your code directly in the question. Not with an image..

Comment: No your code is in your image. But it should be add directly in the question.  
Also what do you mean by 'When I uploaded' ? When the file is send to server by your form. Or when your file is stored ?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570831/get-image-height-and-width-php

Answer (score 34):

```
 $data = getimagesize($filename);
 $width = $data[0];
 $height = $data[1];
```

Comment: And how do you get the filename from an instance of `UploadedImage`? I've tried `path()` and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 15):

Through Intervention Image you can do it as

```
$upload_file = $request->file('gallery_image');
$height = Image::make($upload_file)->height();
$width = Image::make($upload_file)->width();
```

Comment: What is `Image`? Can you please add `use ...\Image;`

Comment: @PiTheNumber The `Image` being referred to is a library called Intervention Image, a very popular and preferred Image library - you can check it out here [Github](https://github.com/Intervention/image) and more documentation here [Intervention Docs](https://image.intervention.io/v2/introduction/installation) - you need to refer to the installation documentation to implement it properly, unfortunately one can't simply `use ...\Image` - but it's worth it!

Answer (score 6):

run

```
composer require intervention/image
```

Then add this to your config/app.php

```
 return [
       ......
       $providers => [
          ......,
          'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
       ],
       $aliases => [
          ......,
          'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
       ]
 ];
```

then use like this.

```
$upload_file = $request->file('gallery_image');
$height = Image::make($upload_file)->height();
$width = Image::make($upload_file)->width();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[$width, $height] = getimagesize($filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 <?php
$imagedetails = getimagesize($_FILES['file-vi']['tmp_name']);

$width = $imagedetails[0];
$height = $imagedetails[1];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an s3 or some file system other than local, you can use `getimagesize($url)`.  The laravel `Storage::disk('s3')->url($file_path)` can provide what the url, however your s3 must be configured as public.  Any url/route to the file will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install `intervention/image` package use this function:

```php
    /**
     * Get file dimension
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $file
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFileDimension(UploadedFile $file): array
    {
        $size = getimagesize($file->getRealPath());

        return [
            'width'     => $size[0] ?? 0,
            'height'    => $size[1] ?? 0,
        ];
    }
```