# How to Show Image Resolution to from its URL

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am creating a website to share wallpapers that can be downloaded and used on users' desktops. But I am not able to find a way to show its resolution to my visitors. Yes, I can write the resolution myself, but the problem is that I share too many images and it is not possible for me to write resolution for each image.

I am able to automatically create description but I want to show the image resolution.

Is it possible with JavaScript to achieve this? No problem if it shows the result after the image loads.

Comment: I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179100/get-image-height-and-width-as-integer-values

Comment: This is PHP, and OP asks for Javascript. But I believe that this can't be achieved client-side without loading all images (which is a big issue)

Comment: Yup. To read the dimensions client-side, you will need to load each of the images. A more performant option, is to pass the image URL to the server via ajax, calculate the dimensions and cache the results, before passing it to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it as an `img` element in JavaScript without rendering it on your page:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

img.src = "path_to_src";
```

Now your image is created, you can pull the height and width using `img.height` and `img.width`, which are obtained once the image loads:

```js
var x = document.createElement('img');

x.src = "http://placehold.it/128x256";

x.onload = function() {
  var html = "";
  
  html += "Height = " + x.height + "px<br>";
  html += "Width = " + x.width + "px";
  
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <!-- Image height and width will be displayed here instead of the below text. -->
    Creating image and pulling its height and width...
</p>
```

Comment: after load I would imagine and how expensive would that be on the client to have to download the full image to see the resolution?

Comment: @mplungjan you don't seem to need to handle that on Chrome. Not sure about other browsers though. I've added an `onload` handler, regardless.

Comment: @mplungjan The issue is that the natural dimensions of the images may be inaccessible until the file is completely loaded.

Comment: you can verify that the entire image is being loaded, by checking the dev-tools network tab.

Comment: It worked... but the result (width and height) are appeared in the first <p> tag and not in the one I want it to appear.

Comment: @Ashish Then just change the `querySelector` to your selector of interest.

Comment: @Ashish I only added that in to easily display that the values had been pulled within the StackOverflow code snippet.

Comment: Thanks... I changed query selector from "p" to "pt". Does this have any problem?. Also, I am able to get the result I want by changing query selector.

Comment: @Ashish `pt` isn't a valid HTML element. What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: Actually... when I used the code it showed the resolution perfectly  but not at the correct place. I want to add it on specific paragraph. The resolution of the images are shown in the first paragraph of my site.

Comment: @Ashish take a look at how `querySelector` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector. My answer here answers the question you've asked. If you have troubles with `querySelector` I suggest you ask a new question and provide any relevant HTML. If you believe my answer has helped, please could you mark it as the accepted answer so that it can be closed? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Now working very well... Give the paragraph an ID and use that ID in the querySelector.

Comment: @Terry yes, I know. Hence my suggestion to use the PHP instead